# Does Google use GWT for their projects? If not what do they use?

Tags: javascript, ajax, gwt

I know this has been asked before but I'd like to ask it here and see what happens.

What do Google's developers use to implement their sites like http://translate.google.com/ for instance. When I look at the source of the page, I'm not immediately seeing anything GWT.

I've been working on a few GWT projects and my experiences with it have been mixed. The advantages are obvious, and I've created dynamic scheme making client-server communication even more transparent. But the downsides have been nagging PITA pretty much. Erroneous hard to find anomalies. Slow building process (I'm familiar with the optimizations and tuning to improve development cycles). Layout hell (css). Plus problems developing for mobiles. No devmode, need various tricks to let me debug and probe inner state. Problems with specific mobiles (eg. Acer A500 disappearing keyboard problem). Mobiles not scaling UI properly. The list of issues goes on and on.

I have the feeling that Google is perfectly well aware of the pitfalls of GWT and use something much better internally for their own apps. Does anyone know how they develop their sites?

Comment: "Google's projects" is way too large a blanket. Some teams use GWT, some use Closure, some might use something entirely different.

Comment: No it is not a way too large a blanket statement Robert. It's quite apparent that most of Google's major web applications are not written using GWT. They prefer Closure over GWT, evidently. My question led to that answer.

Comment: To the 6 people that flagged this for supposedly being off topic: what's off topic about this? This is about programming GWT or alternatives. It helps myself and others determine if GWT is a good technology to program in, or if people should look at other technologies. I'm not understanding the motivation of this seemingly aggressively moderating, and I thing the flagging itself is "off topic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin pages for Adwords is as far as I know done with GWT, as was wave.

For some projects they have used the [Closure library](http://code.google.com/closure/library/)

Gmail is one of these I think.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I wasn't aware of Closure, and Google is indicating that a number of their important web apps are Closure based. I suspected that Google's developers didn't like GWT that much, which this confirms. So my next question would be what about all those widgets? GWT and smartgwt have all these widgets, but from the Closure website I'm not seeing any immediate UI widget demo. How is Google making all their UI components using Closure? Do they have some sort of library that they're not sharing or does the standard Closure library include the widgets you see in their apps?